# Why setWindowSize doesn't work in chrome?

Tags: javascript, dom, automated-tests, webdriver, webdriver-io

I am writing CoffeeScript tests using Webdriver.io and mocha. The code is processed using the CoffeeScript compiler.

I don't know why this command is not working in Chrome ([link to function description](https://webdriver.io/docs/api/browser/setWindowSize/) ):

```
browser.setWindowSize(width, height)
```

There is no error, but the window size does not change.
This command successfully resizes the browser window in Mozilla Firefox.

I also tried to resize the window by writing it to the DOM (when working with webdriver, the object window is not available, so I have to use browser.executeScript)

```
browser.executeScript('window.document.body.style.cssText = "width: 1920px";', []);
browser.executeScript('window.document.body.style.cssText = "heigth: 1080px";', []);
```

There is also no result, the size of the browser window does not change.

How do I resize the browser window in Chrome?

Comment: are you doing something like `browser.setWindowSize(1920, 1080)` ?

Comment: The problem is solved, I reinstalled the web driver and the error disappeared.